# Matchmaking in Dawn of War II

Tags: games-for-windows-live, warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

I have serious issues with match making algorithms in Dawn of War II:

Why does it most often group the noobs together in a team and the pros together in the opposing team?

Noobs can't win that way. So, do I really have to get Rank 20 before I get a chance to win in a Team Battle?

And why are most of my victories not counted in the player statistics? Points get awarded, I even have replays but these victories don't show up in my statistics!

Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a case of memory bias? I.e., you remember the total blowouts because they were total blowouts, and the average matches, on account of them being average, are glossed over in your memory. I'm willing to bet hard money that no match-making system on earth puts the worst players against the best players consistently.

Comment: No, I think he has a point.  I seem to remember pretty awful match-ups too.  It should be a no-brainer that in a 3v3, you don't put all the lvl 20s on a team against all the lvl 5s.  There's a reason Relic is dumping GfW Live for the next expansion

Comment: @Raven Dreamer No, I can prove it. 3 Champion wins on Team Battle recorded. Only 1 victory has been counted! That's unfair!

Comment: I don't know about the victory problem. My comment was geared towards the matchmaking experience exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

I concur.  I found this page looking for an explanation for why single digit levels are grouped against 20+ levels in Team Battle.  Matchmaking seems broken.  I know a recent GfWL update broke the voice chat... did it also break matchmaking?

Edit:  Found a thread in GfWL site that suggests this problem has been here since launch.
http://forums.gamesforwindows.com/t/3358.aspx